# Merge 2 array present in object of available keys be removing specific property of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 objects **a** and **b** which both contains arrays.
I want to  Merge the arrays present in each object and form a new object including the arrays and text nodes.

my code :-

```
  var a = {
            name1:[1,2],
            name2:[3],
            name3:'alisha',
            name4:'japan'
          };

   var b = {
            name1:[4],
            name2:[5,6],
            name3:'hello alisha!!'
          };


 newobject = function (obj1, obj2) {
       var obj3 = {};
       for (var attrname in obj1) {
         obj3[attrname] = obj1[attrname];
       }
       for (var attrname in obj2) {
         obj3[attrname] = obj2[attrname];
       }
        return obj3;
 };

 console.log(newobject(a,b))
```

What I am trying to do :-

I have 2 object **a** & **b** which may contain different data as well as similar data. I want to  mix the data from the arrays if both objects have the same property, If the property of object is a string i want to update it with **b ** objects same property.

**Output may not be accurate but It gives 100% hints to solve this problem**

Output I am trying to get:-

```
  {
        name1:[1,2,4],
        name2:[3,5,6],
        name3:'hello alisha!',
        name4:'japan'
  }
```

**Please don't use jquery**

Comment: how about showing expected output, rather than "100% hints"

Comment: Will the objects only contain `string` and `array` values? Will the arrays  contain nested arrays or objects themselves that need merging? Should arrays be merged based on key or value?

Comment: @JaromandaX That's my guess I wrote it because people may clam me if they don't understand my question.

Comment: @fubar yes array may contain both string and array and array need to be merged based on there keys. But array may not contain nested arrays it only contains textnodes .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's literally the example above that you'd like to merge, then the following will do that for you.

I don't know if it matters in your case, but you may also want to consider handling instances where `a.name1` is a `string` and `b.name1` is an `array`, etc.

```js
var a = {
  name1: [1, 2],
  name2: [3],
  name3: 'alisha',
  name4: 'japan'
};
var b = {
  name1: [4],
  name2: [5, 6],
  name3: 'hello alisha!!'
};

function merge(a, b) {
  var c = {};
  
  for (var key in a) {
    c[key] = a[key];
  }
  
  for (var key in b) {
    c[key] = (Array.isArray(a[key])) ? a[key].concat(b[key]) : b[key];
  }
  
  return c;
}

console.log(merge(a, b));
```

Comment: Nice. just beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

You may easily extend to check for other types as well, like `object` etc.

```
var a = {
  name1:[1,2],
  name2:[3],
  name3:'alisha',
  name4:'japan'
};

var b = {
  name1:[4],
  name2:[5,6],
  name3:'hello alisha!!',
  name5:'new name'
};

function merge(a, b) {
  var c = Object.keys(a).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    if(!(key in b)) {
      acc[key] = a[key]
    } else if(Array.isArray(a[key]) && Array.isArray(b[key])) {
      acc[key] = a[key].concat(b[key])
    } else {
      acc[key] = b[key]
    }
    return acc
  }, {})

  c = Object.keys(b).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    if(!(key in acc)) {
      acc[key] = b[key]
    }
    return acc
  }, c)
  return c
}

var d = merge(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = {
     name1: [1, 2],
     name2: [3],
     name3: 'alisha',
     name4: 'japan'
    };
var b = {
     name1: [4],
     name2: [5, 6],
    name3: 'hello alisha!!'
    };

function mergeObjects(a, b) {
  for (var key in b) {
 a[key] = (Array.isArray(a[key])) ? a[key].concat(b[key]) : b[key];
  }
 return a;
   }

console.log(mergeObjects(a, b));
```